# Why is my value appearing at the start of the string even when it's supposed to be at the end?

Tags: java

"Statuses_count" is supposed to be at the end of the string, but somehow, it appears at the front. I don't understand why, even when other values are in their required order, this one just gets at the start of the string, even when it's supposed to be last. Here's the code.

```
// loop over inner User object
JSONObject user = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("user");
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator_user = user.entrySet().iterator();

while (iterator_user.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iterator_user.next();

    //get user name
    if (entry.getKey().equals("name")) {
        sb.append(entry.getValue()+",");
    }

    //get user followers count
    if (entry.getKey().equals("followers_count")) {
        sb.append(entry.getValue()+",");
    }

    //get user tweets count
    if (entry.getKey().equals("statuses_count")) {
        sb.append(entry.getValue()+",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of things missing in your example to get better answer than:

```
user.entrySet()
```

returns set as far as I can see and set doesn't need  to be sorted (for example `HashSet` is not sorted, `TreeSet` is sorted and `LinkedHashSet` is "sorted")

Correct approach here is not to sort the set, but use the `JSONObject` which is probably map as

```
sb.append(user.get("name"));
sb.append(user.get("followers_count"));
sb.append(user.get("statuses_count"));
```

Comment: Only the last one appears out of order.

Comment: Okay but seems like I can't just change the JSONObject to a TreeSet?

Comment: I assume, you are JSONObject - http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html and there is `get` so you can use it as I wrote... So basically no `while` loop... No need for some conversion, sorting...

Comment: That sorted it. Thanks.